# QuickBooks QBSDK SignonAppCertRq returns a 2020 error

Tags: quickbooks-online, qbxml

I'm developing a webapp which communicates to my customer's QuickBooks Online account via QBSDK.

I'm sending a SignonAppCertRq POST with the connection ticket retrieved from the POST to my app's subscription URL. Everything seems fine, but I'm getting a 2020 error at every try.

Does this mean that the ticket is wrong? The message seems confusing to me. By the way, shouldn't my ticket contain a colon with a number after it? Like "V1-69-120389765417263542678g:97458567". When I append ":12345" to my ticket (12345 is the "appdata" field I set in the login URL), I get a 2000 error saying "Application agent not found".

Here is the XML I post to https://webapps.quickbooks.com/j/AppGateway:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?qbxml version="6.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <SignonMsgsRq>
    <SignonAppCertRq>
      <ClientDateTime>2013-09-29T23:52:00</ClientDateTime>
      <ApplicationLogin>**********</ApplicationLogin>
      <ConnectionTicket>TGT-15-L8DsnyrNM9f***********</ConnectionTicket>
      <Language>English</Language>
      <AppID>8102*****</AppID>
      <AppVer>1</AppVer>
    </SignonAppCertRq>
  </SignonMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

The app is registered as a production QBOE application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this. The "Login security" has to be turned off upon creating the connection. You're not allowed to edit this later.